# Angular - Resolving Observable data before canActivate

Tags: angular, authentication, observable, resolve, canactivate

I’m working on a web application using Angular and i came across a problem. 
There is an Authentication service that logs in a user. I’m sending a request to 
the server with the credentials and waiting for a response. The problem is that I
 try to navigate from the login component to the home component In the subscription 
 of the responded

```
  login(formValues) {
    this.auth.logInUser(formValues.username, formValues.password)
    .subscribe(response =>{
      if(!response){
        this.invalidLogin=true;
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['stream']);
      }
    })
  }
```

---

But every other component has a canActivateGuard that 
 checks whether the current user is logged in (the data that i'm waiting from the server).

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: 'login', resolve: LiveStreamResolver, component: LoginComponent},
    {path: 'reports', component: ReportsComponent, resolve: LiveStreamResolver, canActivate: [AuthGuardService]},
    {path: 'calendar', component: CalendarComponent, resolve: LiveStreamResolver, canActivate: [AuthGuardService]},
    {path: 'stream', component: LiveStreamComponent},
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full'}
];
```

---

```
constructor(public auth: AuthenticationService) { }

  canActivate(): boolean {
    return !!this.auth.currUser;
  }
```

Is there a way to resolve before the canActivate check is done? Is there any others solutions maybe? 

 Any other advises for how to guard the components would be welcomed :D

Comment: Please check the updated answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue and here is how I resolved it.

You can return `Observable<boolean>` from canActivate method. Try returning Observable instead of pure boolean.

Also, another option is, you can return promise.

Have a look at [CanActivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate#description).

Here is the code sample:

**AuthenticationService**

```
    @Injectable()
    export class AuthenticationService {

        private isAuthenticatedSubject = new ReplaySubject<boolean>(0);
        public isAuthenticated = this.isAuthenticatedSubject.asObservable();

    constructor() { }

    /* Call this method once user successfully logged in. It will update the isAuthenticatedSubject*/
    setAuth() {
       this.isAuthenticatedSubject.next(true);
     }

   }
```

**AuthgaurdService**

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthgaurdService implements CanActivate {

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private authService: AuthenticationService) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
        // this will return Observable<boolean>
        return this.authService.isAuthenticated.pipe(take(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you control if the observable fails or user is not authenticated? The page hangs out / does nothing

Answer (score 0):

You can use obervable , here is an exemple :

```
constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
    if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
        return true;
    }
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;
}
```